# Heroku Knex Migration with Typescript

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, heroku, knex.js

I am trying to make a migration on my heroku database with knex and typescript.

When I try "knex migrate:make migrationname -x ts" on Heroku I just get a message that within knexfile.ts some import didn't work.

Is Heroku able to work with knexfile.ts anyway or is there a better way?

**error log from Heroku Console:**

```
Failed to load external module ts-node/register
Failed to load external module typescript-node/register
Failed to load external module typescript-register
Failed to load external module typescript-require
Failed to load external module sucrase/register/ts
Failed to load external module @babel/register
/app/knexfile.ts:1
import dotenv from "dotenv";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at importFile (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/util/import-file.js:12:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok fixed it with a little of help of somebody else. Heroku should compile all ts-files to js-files and can run those js-files with the built-in node. It's a good practice to compile all js into a build folder like /build/knexfile.js and then run knex commands like "knex migrate:latest --knexfile /build/knexfile.js" on heroku itself. Either via heroku bash or from terminal.